# Adjusting table to \textwidth with calc and \p{}

Tags: tables

The following tabular environment has 3 columns. Each column has a width of `\textwidth/3`, but somehow the table is wider than `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{||p{\textwidth/3}||p{\textwidth/3}|p{\textwidth/3}||}
aaaaaaa&bbbbbbbb&cccccccccc\\
\end{tabular}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

What might the problem be?

Comment: You are not allowing for the inter-column separation. Do you want to remove this entirely or to allow for it?

Comment: @JosephWright There won't be any space betweeen the columns.

Comment: If you remove the vertical rules (that are bad typography anyway), just saying `p{\textwidth/3 - 2\tabcolsep}` will do.

Comment: Adding `- 2\tabcolsep` fixed the problem. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `tabularx` makes more sense in this special case

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|| X || X | X ||}
aaaaaaa&bbbbbbbb&cccccccccc\\
\end{tabularx}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```